# Regex porque apenas true se colocar acima de 5 números?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```js
function checkreg() {
  var reg = /[0-9]{4}/;
  var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#agencia").value;
  console.log(reg.test(verificaInput))
}
```

```html
<label>
   <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia"/>
   <input type="button" value="click to check" onclick="checkreg(this.id)"/>
</label>
```

gostaria de saber porquê este código apresenta apenas true até mesmo acima de 5 números digitados?

Comment: Porque seu regex está limitando que seja um número de apenas  `{4}` algarismos... como vc não definiu o início e o fim, ele vai validar isso para 4 números apenas.

Comment: Complementando as respostas abaixo, vc também pode usar `\d` no lugar de `[0-9]`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-digit

Answer (score 5):

Ela não retorna `true` **apenas** quando coloca 5 dígitos ou mais, é quando coloca 4 ou mais, pois o que a sua expressão regular define é "veja se há 4 dígitos entre 0 e 9". Qualquer valor composto com 4 ou mais dígitos irá possuir 4 dígitos. Na verdade, qualquer valor que possua 4 dígitos consecutivos irá fazer o retorno ser verdadeiro, como `"abc1234xyz"`, tal como lembrado pelo [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/414904/regex-porque-apenas-true-se-colocar-acima-de-5-n%c3%bameros/414909?noredirect=1#comment808621_414909).

Se a ideia é que seja válido **apenas com 4 dígitos**, basta limitar a regex com os caracteres `^` e `$` que, respectivamente, indicam o início e o final do valor, portanto contendo apenas o que deseja.

```js
function checkreg() {
  var reg = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
  var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#agencia").value;

  console.log(reg.test(verificaInput))

}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia"/>
  <input type="button" value="click to check" onclick="checkreg(this.id)"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Na verdade, se a string for `abc1234xyz`, também dá *match*, pois quando a regex  não tem marcadores como `^` e `$`, ela procura por 4 dígitos em qualquer ponto da string

Comment: @hkotsubo Essa era a minha intenção, mas acabei não *prevendo* essa situação haha valeu

Answer (score 1):

O problema estava apenas no seu `regex`, o correto é:

```
var reg = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/;
```

Totalizando `length` máximo de 4 dígitos, sendo necessário também o marcador `^` para verificar dentro dos números e não da String.

```js
function checkreg() {
  var reg = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/;
  var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#agencia").value;
  console.log(reg.test(verificaInput))
}
```

```html
<label>
   <input type="number" name="agencia" id="agencia" />
  <input type="button" value="click to check" onclick="checkreg(this.id)" />
</label>
```